# Removing duplicate characters from pairs

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a document in Notepad++ where each line can have combination of characters that are double and I want them to be single only.
For example:

```
((AA11BB88CCCC)) -> (A1B8CC)
```

That is deleting a duplicate character for each pair (2) of characters.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing group and backreference.

Find:

```
(.)\1
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

[image]

Comment: @Unihedron, Ah, I got it. It's Korean font that display the backslash (`\ `) as Korean currency (Won, `￦`).